# How to calculate work hours per project per employee

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP form that inputs empID, projectNumber, and clock-in/clock-out time-stamp into a MySQL table like this:

Having no reputation, I can't post image, so take a look here:
[screenshot http://mailed.in/timecard/ss1.jpg](http://mailed.in/timecard/ss1.jpg)

I need help in generating a report that looks like this:
[screenshot http://mailed.in/timecard/ss2.jpg](http://mailed.in/timecard/ss2.jpg)

Can I do this entirely in MySQL? How?

Comment: How do you verify that they have a clock-out for every clock-in?

Comment: I don't verify. If they haven't clocked-out, the record just won't show.

Comment: Well, you can correlate a row with the previous row matching the project, then use a date function to get the difference. However, my fear is (with absent data) you're going to see things (potentially) go in to the days for time. Also, one missed clock in/will then reverse any future entries (you'd then be getting difference from out to in, instead of in to out, thereafter)

Comment: The table structure in the image doesn't say anything about clock out time...

Comment: Brad, can you give example how to "correlate a row with previous row matching the project"? I think that's what I need to know. Thanks.

Comment: Dvir, the "Clock Time" column contains BOTH clock-in and clock-out time-stamps. We assume that the first time-stamp for each project must be the clock-in, and the subsequent time-stamp must be the clock-out.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

```
SELECT 
    empID AS EmpID, 
    projectNumber AS ProjectNumber, 
    DATE(clocktime) AS StartDate,  
    TIMEDIFF(
      (SELECT max(clocktime) from tableName where DATE( `clocktime` ) = CURDATE( )), 
      (SELECT min(clocktime) from tableName where DATE( `clocktime` ) = CURDATE( ))
    ) AS WorkHours
FROM `tableName`
WHERE 
DATE( `clocktime` ) = CURDATE( )
GROUP BY empID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
CREATE TABLE table_proj (
  empid INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  projectnumber INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  clocktime DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_proj VALUES 
  (1, 1, '2011-09-27 10:02:22'),
  (1, 1, '2011-09-27 11:17:32'),
  (2, 2, '2011-09-27 11:34:13'),
  (3, 3, '2011-09-27 11:01:21'),
  (3, 3, '2011-09-27 13:36:28'),
  (2, 2, '2011-09-27 13:55:39'),
  (4, 4, '2011-09-27 14:25:07');

SELECT
  empid, projectnumber, MIN(clocktime) startdate, TIMEDIFF(MAX(clocktime), MIN(clocktime)) workhours
FROM
  table_proj
GROUP BY
  empid, projectnumber
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2;

+-------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+
| empid | projectnumber | startdate           | workhours |
+-------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+
|     1 |             1 | 2011-09-27 10:02:22 | 01:15:10  |
|     2 |             2 | 2011-09-27 11:34:13 | 02:21:26  |
|     3 |             3 | 2011-09-27 11:01:21 | 02:35:07  |
+-------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+
```